# Find if point lies on Bezier line created By DrawBezier function

Tags: c#, gdi+, bezier

I have Bezier line created by C# `DrawBezier` function with four points `S(x1,y1)`, `E(x2,y2)`, `C1(x3,y3`), `C2(x4,y4)`. The S and E are endpoints, and C1 and C2 are control points. How can I check if the point `p(x,y)` lays on the Bezier line?

Comment: Small nit: why are you checking if a 3d coordinate is on a 2d path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing so analytically in math is rather hard, but the built-in GDI+ methods come to the rescue..:

Create a `GraphicsPath` that is exactly the same and use the `GraphicsPath.IsVisible(Point)` method

```
 using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
 ..
```

Lets assume you draw your bezier curve like this:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawBezier(yourPen, yourParameterList );
```

Then this will tell you if a point lies on it:

```
 GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
 gp.AddBezier(yourParameterList);
 if (gp.IsVisible(yourPoint)) .. //do your stuff;
```

And of course you can replace the `DrawBezier` by a `DrawPath`:

```
 e.Graphics.DrawPath(yourPen, gp);
```